# R Shiny: htmlOutput removes white spaces I need

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a string like this for example:

```
SomeName                     SomeValue
A much longer name           AnotherValue
Even longer name than before NewValue
```

Let's say I have this text correctly in a R variable like

```
variable<-"SomeName                     SomeValue<br\>A much longer name           AnotherValue<br\>Even longer name than before NewValue<br\>
```

In my ui.R:

```
...htmlOutput("TextTable")
```

And in my server.R

```
output$TextTable<- renderUI({
    HTML(variable)
  })
```

But the output isn't the way I want it. All white spaces are deleted except one. So the "columns" aren't as they should be in my output. How can I avoid this?

Comment: What does `HTML` function do? It may be stripping whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, browsers tend to shorten consecutive whitespaces in HTML code to a single character.  Don't put the whitespace in your r variable.  Store the data as a matrix, and use `renderTable`.

```
##server.R
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  variable = c("SomeName","SomeValue","A much longer name","AnotherValue","Even longer name than before", "NewValue")
  variable = matrix(data = variable, ncol = 2)  
    output$TextTable<- renderTable({variable},include.rownames = FALSE,include.colnames = FALSE)
})

##ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("TextTable")
    )
  )
))
```

### Update

On the other hand, if your text is already in that format, you can prevent a browser from collapsing whitespace using the `<pre>` tag.  In your case, you could use the following code:

```
output$TextTable<- renderUI(HTML(paste0("<pre>",variable,"</pre>")))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. My textfile is used to display data in exactly this format and imported as textfile also into word etc. So I need to work with these whitespaces and I need them to be displayed

Comment: You're right, I didn't really answer your actual question.  Hopefully the change I just made to my answer is better suited to your situation.